# Parsing C and Java for displaying code on my website

Tags: java, c, parsing, web

I have hosted my web-application on google appengine. I had to put up some java code on my website.So I am looking for a java parser for the website. Please suggest some.

Actually I wanted to put up a project that used `C` and `Java` so I am looking for a parser that can parse both the languages.Are there available parser or I will have to write my own ?

*Edit : My sole purpose 'now' is code highlighting*

Comment: Could you clarify what is the purpose of a parser for you? Do you require simple code highlighting, or do you want an actual parser for online code injection?

Comment: It is unclear what your intention is. What is your intended purpose of parsing the files? Is it for syntax highlighting, data extraction, or something else? (edit: beaten by 19 seconds haha)

Comment: Then an answer has been provided that matches this question, to my reckoning. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need code highlighting, there are tons of stuff out there. You could, for instance, use [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/), or even [Google's own code prettifier](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

At this moment, that is what I can get from your question, so until further clarification, I won't be able to give a more precise answer.